# sailsjs array query Exact match

Tags: sails.js, waterline

i want to query mongodb in sailsjs.
this is structure of my db

```
{
    "users": [
        "52ed09e1d015533c124015d5",
        "52ed4bc75ece1fb013fed7f5"
    ],
    "user_msgs": [
        {
            "sender": "52ed09e1d015533c124015d5",
            "sendTo": "52ed4bc75ece1fb013fed7f5",
            "msg": "ss"
        }
    ],
    "createdAt": ISODate("2014-02-06T16:12:17.751Z"),
    "updatedAt": ISODate("2014-02-06T16:12:17.751Z"),
    "_id": ObjectID("52f3b461f46da23c111582f6")
}
```

I want to search those "users" who who match array

```
  [
        "52ed09e1d015533c124015d5",
        "52ed4bc75ece1fb013fed7f5"
    ]
```

```
Message.find({user: ["52ed09e1d015533c124015d5","52ed4bc75ece1fb013fed7f5"]})
```

this query returns all objects which contains 1 OR 2 ..but i need only those which exacly match 1 AND 2,
i have also tried $all, and etc.. but did not worked 
please tell me how to write query with sailsjs supported syntex to get those user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the native Mongo adapter for this:

```
Message.native(function(err, collection) {

   collection.find({users:{'$all':["52ed09e1d015533c124015d5","52ed4bc75ece1fb013fed7f5"]}}).toArray(function(err, results) {

     // Do something with results

   });

});
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
Message.find()
.where({users: "52ed09e1d015533c124015d5", "52ed4bc75ece1fb013fed7f5"})
.exec(function(){
  // do something
});
```

While the above code may work to pull in just those users. I think a better solution would be to define your user ID's in your message model.

I would add the following attributes to your messages model:

```js
senderID: {
   type: 'string'
},
receiverID: {
   type: 'string'
}
```

Now you can make that query more efficient by using the following query:

```js
Message.find()
.where({senderID: "52ed09e1d015533c124015d5"})
.where({receiverID: "52ed4bc75ece1fb013fed7f5"})
.exec(function(){
  // do something
});
```

This is the route I would take.

Comment: Thanks for your answer .but it did not worked for me. the above schema i made for mongodb to allow 1-1 and multi-user chat..like group conversation.in "users" array i want to stroe those user ID's that are in this chat.and while retriving data i want the EXACT array of user.. where also returns all objects who have one of them

Comment: This is incorrect syntax: `.where({users: "52ed09e1d015533c124015d5", "52ed4bc75ece1fb013fed7f5"})`