# MongoDB find $in not working in sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I'm creating a simple application with Sail.js, and its Waterline ORM. For part of this, I'm following NoSQL's equivalent of a pivot table pattern: each user has an array, `subscriptions`, of all channels they're subscribed to. I'm attempting to find all users subscribed to a particular channel id, using the following:

```
User.find({subscriptions: {$in: [req.param('channel')]}}).done(function (err, users) {
   /* ... */
});
```

Not the most beautiful line of code every written, but it *should* work. The issue is, it doesn't. `users` is an empty array, and `err` is null. They query actual executed is, for example (using the Node Inspector):

```
{ subscriptions: { '$in': [ '52fd1a033004de2d9bcb4980' ] } }
```

When this same query is used to "find" users via the umongo GUI, it works correctly. However, no users are found when the function is executed.

And ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the $in to find something inside an array. A simple find will do the trick:

```
db.users.find({subscriptions : '52fd1a033004de2d9bcb4980'})
```

All users with that channel will be returned.

Comment: Ah, thank you! A bit new to Mongo, though, if anyone does know, I'd be curious to why my initial code didn't work.

Comment: $in require the record to be in the array you provide. It does not require the value you provide to be in a record array.

Comment: For instance, you want all users with the first name being john, peter or paul: db.users.find({firstName : {$in : ['john', 'peter', 'paul']}}). It's kind of the other way around of how you were using it.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks! The more I play around with Mongo, the cooler it seems.

Comment: This is valid mongo but doesn't answer the original question as to how to do the query in Sails...

Comment: @ScottGress I'm not familiar with sails.js and just tried to help.

Comment: @joao no problem man :) Sails/Waterline makes basic queries like this pretty simple cross-database.  In general, the less you need to rely on native queries, the better, since it makes your application code more portable (i.e. if you want to switch to PostgreSQL or MySQL or Redis in the future for one or all of your models, it'll all still work)

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI, the accepted answer is a valid Mongo query but not valid Sails code.  You want:

```
User.find({subscriptions: req.param('channel')}).done(function (err, users) {
  /* ... */
});
```

The reason your original code didn't work is that the Sails ORM (Waterline) doesn't understand native Mongo operators like `$in`.  However, since it uses the underlying Mongo adapter to perform the `find` operation, a search for a single channel will match any records that include that channel in their `subscriptions` array.  Note that if you ever do need to use low-level Mongo operators (like `$all`) you can use the `native` method of your model class to get access to the underlying Mongo adapter.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608919/sailsjs-array-query-exact-match/21786493#21786493) for more details.